# isLoading logic for svelte video element

Tags: javascript, html5-video, render, svelte, loading

How would I implement an 'isLoading' spinner for a video that is not done loading, in svelte? The video src is passed in from a parent element. By this time I have the src url. I think the issue is its takes a brief second to play it. maybe buffering?. I want to show a spinner while its doing this. is this possible? Maybe something like this below.
Is there like a buffering or playing property for video? if so I could change a variable when its done.

```
<script>
export let mySrc;
let isLoaded = false;

const loadHandler = (value) => {
  isLoaded = value;
}

</script>

{#if mySrc && isLoaded}
  <video src={mySrc} on:canPlay={loadHandler(true)}/> 
{:else}
  <Spinner/>
{/if}
```

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to listen to events like [`canplay`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/canplay_event). So add an `on:canplay` handler and set your loading flag to `false` that way (set it to `true` when the source changes, which should trigger `loadstart`).

There also is a [`waiting`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/waiting_event) event that is triggered if you run out of buffer. (Though, making the video disappear when that happens may not be a good idea.)

(See e.g. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video#events) or [the spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/media.html#mediaevents) for event listings.)

---

Example:

```html
<script>
    export let src;
    
    let isLoading = true;
</script>

<video {src} controls
       on:loadstart={() => isLoading = true}
       on:canplay={() => isLoading = false}
       class:loading={isLoading} />

{#if isLoading}
    Loading...
{/if}

<style>
    video { width: 100%; }
    .loading { display: none; }
</style>
```

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/45450463f2dc4907a39bda3bd19c49fa?version=3.50.1)

Comment: the second bit i am confused about, inside the handler I would set isLoading to true, but if is Loading is false the video element wont render meaning the canplay event will never start

Comment: edited above trying to do what you recommended

Comment: You would have to change your template logic. Always add the video element, only hide it *visually* while the data is being loaded. Also, casing probably matters, all events are lowercase.

Comment: Added an example.

Comment: The example will stuck on 'Loading...' if it fails to serve the video from the src link. In that case: `on:error={() => console.log('error')}`.